# What i want to know is do you have clean your bedsheets if you masturbate?

Tags: halal-haram, masturbation

I have been masturbating for a while now and I'm trying my best to stop.

I have been masturbating I have been rubbing my private part in my underwear until semen has come out and gone on my underwear but not my bedsheets.

Do I need to wash my bedsheets or Not

Answer (score 0):

Why would you need to wash your bedsheet. You just have clean your clothes which has the The Najis(impurities).

If there is no impurity in in your bedsheet there is no need to  wash your bedsheet. And you also need to take a proper bath to make yourself pure.

Thanks